# ScheduledTimerTask prevent overlap

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I'm using spring's ScheduledTimerTask to schedule some tasks to schedule some tasks.

```
<bean id="someScheduler" class="com.example.scheduler.SomeScheduler">
</bean>

<bean id="anotherScheduler" class="com.example.scheduler.SomeScheduler">
</bean>

<bean id="someImport" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="someScheduler" />
</bean>

<bean id="anotherImport" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="anotherScheduler" />
</bean>
```

How to make sure anotherScheduler won't execute when someScheduler is being executed?

Comment: Do you want them to run one after the other, or those tasks have their own shedule and may run whenever and there is a slight possibility they can overlap?

Comment: They may run whenever.

Comment: Difficult. I think you may need some kind of central scheduler that should check for overlapping. Out-of-the-box and with Spring I don't think there is such option.